# a row for every json key/value pair in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

My PostgreSQL 13.0 table looks like this:

```
  TIMESTAMP(bigint)  | PAYLOAD(jsonb)
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  1610986488 | {"1": foo, "2": bar, "3": baz}
  1610986485 | {"1": qux, "2": quux, "3": corge }
  1610986438 | {"1": grault, "2": garply, "3": waldo }
```

I want to get this:

```
  TIMESTAMP  | id |  data
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  1610986488 |  1 | foo 
  1610986488 |  2 | bar
  1610986488 |  3 | baz
  1610986485 |  1 | qux
  1610986485 |  2 | quux
  1610986485 |  3 | corge
  1610986438 |  1 | grault
  1610986438 |  2 | garply
  1610986438 |  3 | waldo
```

I fiddled with the json_to_something() functions with no luck.

I know how to hardcode my way there (but I would like to keep the same code if I receive more or less than 3 values) or manipulate the json string in order to make it a regular array and `unnest()` it but I would like to know the correct and possibly elegant solution. Thanks

Comment: Totally unrelated, but: I find a column named "timestamp" that doesn't contain a `timestamp` highly confusing.

Comment: that's a Unix timestamp https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: Oh you meant the data type. Nevermind that, it was just an example. Don't worry, what's on the actual table is way worse than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `jsonb_each_text()` (unnest is for arrays)

```
select t."timestamp", 
       p.*
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each_text(t.payload) as p(id, data)
```